# Display Different Information Based on URL

Tags: php

It says I have an error on line 10 and not sure why

heres my code:

```
<?php
$os1= (isset($_GET['number']) && ($_GET['number'] == 'one' || $_GET['number'] == 'two' || $_GET['number'] == 'three'));
$os2= (isset($_GET['number']) && ($_GET['number'] == 'four' || $_GET['number'] == 'five' || $_GET['number'] == 'six'));


if ($os1)
 {
$title = "Windows 8";
$title2 = "User"
 }

else ($os2)
 {
$title = "OSX Yosimite";
$title2 = "User"
 }


 echo $title1;
 echo $title2;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `;` on two places:

```
if ($os1)
 {
$title = "Windows 8";
$title2 = "User"; // add ; here
 }

else ($os2)
 {
$title = "OSX Yosimite";
$title2 = "User"; // add ; here
 }
```

Change

```
else ($os2)
```

to

```
else if ($os2)
```

The above logic fits as solution as if we just use `else` instead of `else if`, there is no use of the variable `$os2`.

Again

Change

```
echo $title1;
```

to

```
echo $title;
```

Answer (score 0):

missin ; in line no 10 & 15

```
   <?php
    $os1= (isset($_GET['number']) && ($_GET['number'] == 'one' || $_GET['number'] == 'two' || $_GET['number'] == 'three'));
    $os2= (isset($_GET['number']) && ($_GET['number'] == 'four' || $_GET['number'] == 'five' || $_GET['number'] == 'six'));


    if ($os1)
     {
    $title = "Windows 8";
    $title2 = "User";
     }

    else ($os2)
     {
    $title = "OSX Yosimite";
    $title2 = "User";
     }


     echo $title1;
     echo 

$title2;
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Variable "$title1" is not defined any where (OR) Not assign any value before print.

echo $title1;

Answer (score 0):

You have missed semicolon(;) at the end of line numbers 9 and 15. Please check.

Every line should end with a semicolon in PHP, other wise it scolds us with an error :-D

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php
   $arr1=array("one","two","three");
   $arr2= array("four","five","six");
   if(isset($_GET['number']) && in_array($_GET['number'],$arr1))
   {
       $title = "Windows 8";
       $title2 = "User";
   }
   elseif (if(isset($_GET['number']) && in_array($_GET['number'],$arr2)))
   {
         $title = "OSX Yosimite";
         $title2 = "User";
   }


   echo $title;
   echo $title2;
 ?>
```

Hope it will work for you.